# Are the two integrals equivalent?

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

Consider $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)$ continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ and the integral
$$
g(A):=\int_{x \in A}^{} f(x) dx
$$
Is $g(A)$ equal to the integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}1\{x \in A\}f(x) dx
$$
where $1\{ \}$ is the indicator function taking value 1 if $x \in A$ and zero otherwise?

Comment: Yes they are indeed the same

Comment: My doubt is the following: suppose that $A$ is a continuous function of $\theta \in \Theta \subseteq \mathbb{R}$; then $g(A_\theta)$ is continuous over $\Theta$ because the integration region is continuous over $\Theta$. In the second case $1\{x \in A_\theta\}$ does not look continuous over $\Theta$. How can they be equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}1\{x \in A\}f(x) dx=
\int_{\mathbb{R}\backslash A}^{}1\{x \in A\}f(x) dx+\int_{A}^{}1\{x \in A\}f(x) dx
.$$
We know that, $$\int_{\mathbb{R}\backslash A}^{}1\{x \in A\}f(x) dx=0,$$ since $x\notin A.$

And we know that $$\int_{A}^{}1\{x \in A\}f(x) dx=\int_{A}^{}f(x) dx,$$ since $x\in A.$

Hence,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}^{}1\{x \in A\}f(x) dx=\int_{A}^{}f(x) dx.$$

Comment: I don't understand equation 3, is it an assumption?

Comment: @user141303 I edited the answer.